java con jpanel y multiventanas
buenos dias,tardes y noches, mas que un problema es una duda, tengo un proyecto el cual  en la revision del mismo me pide que no abra tantas ventanas, lo que quiero saber es que si es posible que estas ventanas se abran en el espacio sin datos(el panel derecho) cada una de las opciones, cabe destacar que no esta echo como proyecto Jframe, fue escrito desde cero.
si hay solucion a eso o de plano debo empezar ha hacerlo de nuevo en seria de ayuda ya que esta practicamente terminado solo pidieron corregir esa parte.
